# Can you link NASM assembled files with MSVC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, nasm

Is there a way to use any of visual studio's tools to link this [code](http://web.archive.org/web/20120414223112/http://www.cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmexamples/).

```
        global  _main
        extern  _printf

        section .text
_main:
        push    message
        call    _printf
        add     esp, 4
        ret
message:
        db      'Hello, World', 10, 0
```

I can do it with gcc, but I would like to know if there is a way without using gcc. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a C++ project and set the tool to masm ?

Comment: @RolfHuisman I'm trying to do it from console, and I'm getting problems with the linker that comes with VS14.

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors with that ?

Comment: yeah, I kinda fixed it using an older linker version (14.0 was not working, used 12.0) the error was unresolved _printf symbol (linking against the C lib msvcrt.lib)

Answer (score 1):

Guess I'm a bit late to the party.

Yes, you can link it. Although it takes a bit of work to get it going. In general, `nasm -f win32` should produce Microsoft compatible object code. See their [manual page](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.2) for details.

If you want to use this along with Visual Studio, try following [this page](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2009/fall/cs301/nasm_vcpp/). In general, you add your `.asm` file to project and then use Custom Build option -> Command Line to set `nasm.exe -f win32 -o $(OutputPath) $(InputPath)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MSVC linker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2fck18t.aspx) - the linker options page is especially helpful, with a list of the command-line arguments available for the tool.

If you need a kick-start, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125613/msvc-using-link-exe-manually) has information on running it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio for some time now includes MASM to assemble your code and of course it has the linker to build the corresponding executable.
You can do it even within the IDE; it is dependent on VS version though. Take a look i.e. here [Assembly Programming with Visual Studio 2010/2012](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271627/Assembly-Programming-with-Visual-Studio) from this link you'll see the linker parameters used in VS 2010/2012, 2014 shouldn't change much for a simple program like yours. Even when the examples are made within the IDE VS also shows the command line parameters corresponding to the final link.